# What is this style of webpack syntax: imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I am looking through a webpack config that contains the following code:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  fetch: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
}),
```

I see from the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) that `ProvidePlugin` replaces the value on the left (fetch) with the modules on the right wherever it finds it, with no `import` necessary.

I can follow the examples in the docs, for example

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

loads in the jquery module wherever `$` or `jQuery` is encountered in the code. But my code doesn't look like a js module, so what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is `imports-loader` and `exports-loader` syntax: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/.